# how can i store more than one session data in httpsession?is there any other way to store

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
servlet code
for (int i=0;i<StudentValues.studentmap.size();i++){
            System.out.println("size"+i);
            HttpSession session= request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("id", std.getStudentId());

            session.setAttribute("fname", std.getFirstName());
            session.setAttribute("mname", std.getMiddleName());
            session.setAttribute("lname", std.getLastName());
            session.setAttribute("faname", std.getFatherName());
            session.setAttribute("maname", std.getMotherName());
            session.setAttribute("address", std.getAddressDetails());
            session.setAttribute("total", std.getTotalMarks());
            session.setAttribute("grade", std.getGrade());



        }
```

here i created the session to hold the data.but only the last data is getting passed to jsp what to do

```
and my jsp code
<%
    int size=StudentValues.studentmap.size();
%>

<%
    for(int i=0;i <size;i++)
    {
%>
    <tr>

            <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("id"));%></td>

        <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("fname"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("mname"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("lname"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("faname"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("maname"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("address"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("total"));%></td>
                <td><%out.println(session.getAttribute("grade"));%></td>


    </tr>
<%
    }   
%>
</table>
```

i have used dynamic table concept to hold those data but only the last data i am getting in the table. how can i get all data which i entered several times

Comment: can you print out the various values inside the servlet please. It really should work, so I suspect that the values are actually empty.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "only the last data I am getting in the table? Do you only get one cell? Or multiple cells all with the value of the last attribute? or all cells, but only the last one contains data?

Comment: Why you want use session, you are calling `StudentValues.studentmap.size()` in both your jsp and servlet. Which means your data already available to your jsp, why again session and servlet?

Answer (score 2):

You should do this using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm). Using scriplets in JSP is a [bad practice](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets).

In servelt, simply set the whole student map as an attribute:

```
session.setAttribute("students", studentMap);
```

In jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<table>
    <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
         <tr>
             <td>${student.mname}</td>
             <td>${student.address}</td>
             <td>${student.grade}</td>
         </tr>       
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only get the last values because these names **"id"**,**"fname"**,**"mname"**,**"lname"**,**"faname"**,**"maname"**,**"address"**,**"total"**,**"grade"** have to be unique so when you iterate you override the previous value so you only get the last values in your List

what you are actually doing is `x=5` then `x=7` then `x=9` so you only get the last value

you can store your Array on session and iterate in jsp using JSTL tags

in servlet:

```
session.setAttribute("myList", studentList);
```

in jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="element"> 
<tr>
     <td>${element.id}</td>
     <td>${element.fname}</td>
     <td>${element.mname}</td>
     <td>${element.lname}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of a session are basically a map.

What you probably want to do is just have one attribute "students" and store a List of students in there. Then iterate over the thing in order to create your table.

Answer (score 0):

To store the session values into session object,

`session.setAttribute("ref-name", Session value)`;

Instead of getting values in jsp using

```
Scriptlet Tag
(<% 
       //Java code 
%>)
```

Use JSTL tag library like this,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

You can access the session values in anywhere in the jsp page.

```
<!-- Session Values-->
<c:set var="userId" value="${sessionScope['fname']}"></c:set>
```

Second way,

```
session.setAttribute("students", studentList);
```

Use `Expression Langauage(EL - $)` in JSP

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
         <tr>
             <td>${student.fname}</td>
             <td>${student.userid}</td>
         </tr>       
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the std object into session from servlet and get it from jsp page.

add to session in servlet

```
  session.setAttribute("std",std);
```

get from session in jsp

```
Student std=(Student)session.getAttribute("std");

out.println(std.getFirstName());
```